# cannot relaunch the app when we use foreground service using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms for my app. I am using foreground service for my app to work on background. I kill the App and when I try to relaunch the App, I can't open the App. Here I am adding My service code below. Please see the code and give me suggestions to solve this issue.

My Service Code is below:
MyPrjService.cs:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android;
using Android.Media;
using MyPrj.Interface;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Android.Net;
using MyPrj.Common;
using MyPrj.Services;
using Android.App;
using MyPrj.BusinessLogic;
using MyPrj.Helper;
using System;
using Plugin.Connectivity;
using MyPrj.Form;
using Android.Graphics;

namespace MyPrj.Droid.Services
{
    [Service]
    public class MyPrjService : Service
    {
        CancellationTokenSource _cts;
        private static ILogger logger = DependencyService.Get<ILogManager>().GetLog();
        public const string LOCATION_CHANNEL = "default";
        NotificationManager manager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            manager = (NotificationManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService("notification");
        }
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            StartLocationServiceForeground();

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        void StartLocationServiceForeground()
        {
            try
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
                {
                    var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(LOCATION_CHANNEL,
                       new Java.Lang.String("Primary"), NotificationImportance.High);
                    manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);

                    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Forms.Context, LOCATION_CHANNEL);
                    notification.SetOngoing(true)
                        //.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon))
                     .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_transparent)
                     .SetContentTitle("MyPrj  is running background")
                        .SetContentText("Tab for more information or to stop the app")
                        .SetColor(0x9c6114)
                             .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh);

                    StartForeground(1, notification.Build());
                }
            }
            catch(System.Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }


        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            StopForeground(true);
            if (manager!=null)
            {
                manager.CancelAll();
            }
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override async void OnSleep()
{
            try
            {
var context = Droid.MainActivity.Instance;
                                if (context != null)
                                {
                                    context.StartServiceFromApp();
                                }
            }
}
 protected async override void OnResume()
        {
            var context = Droid.MainActivity.Instance;
            if (context != null)
            {
                context.StopServiceFromApp();
            }
}
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
public void StartServiceFromApp()
        {

os 9
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                var intent1 = new Intent(this, typeof(MyPrjService));
                StartService(intent1);
            }
        }
public void StopServiceFromApp()
        {
            var intent1 = new Intent(this, typeof(ScoularService));
            StopService(intent1);
        }
```

Comment: It seems like you don't have an override to OnResume() so your app just continues with the StartServiceFromApp code. Override the OnResume and kill the intent1 service that you started. Did you use the wrong override, you mean to use OnResume instead of your OnDestroy?

Comment: i already stop the service on OnResume method like above code

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test with it?

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay. The code above is working fine. Problem is based on my splash screen code.